# Naming a behavior in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset on height that looks like below.

```
Height Phase
0      A
2      A
3      A
4      P
4      P
3      D
2      D
1      D
0      D .
```

I want to create a second column called Phase as above that tells Ascent, Peak, or Descent at corresponding height. I tried to use the `IF` function as `IF(HeiPh="A",B3>=B2,IF(HeiPh="P",4,"D"))` . However i'm not getting the required result. I have a big dataset and there are height that is same for few times i.e. like 0 2 2 3 4 5 5 5 5 6 and so  on

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IF(A2=MAX(A:A),"P",IF(ROW(A2)<MATCH(MAX(A:A),A:A,0),"A","D"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this `=IF(MAX($A$4:$A$13)=A4,"P",IFS(A5>=A4,"A",A5<A4,"D"))`

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7qyz.png]

Comment: On the data set {1,2,3,4,5,5,4,4,3,2,1,0} then second 4 will get a `A` when it should be `D` This may never happen but just an FYI.

Comment: Also in your picture it shows the last 0 as `A` when it should be `D`

Comment: Equal is at the bad place, to fix : =SI(MAX($A$4:$A$14)=A7;"P";SI.CONDITIONS(A8>A7;"A";A8<=A7;"D"))

Comment: Now if the double is before the peak it will show `D` in the first.  `0 2 2 3 4 5 5 5 5 6` The first `2` will show `D` instead of `A` like it should.